# How you deal with logging stacktrace using lombok in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging, lombok

For security reason I decided to avoid printStackTrace to the console.
Instead, I'm doing

```
log.error("Error occored: {}", e);
```

Now, this solution work as the stacktrace is shown only in the log file and not
in the consule.
While this approcah is good for prod, the developer in local environment can't see the stack trace in his consule which impact productity.
What is the best practive and how you achieve this without injecting too many dependecies into
all service class. What is the proffesional way of doing this?

UPDATE
Using the above code, both the consule and log file showing the stacktrace which is good for dev. Now I need to know what need to configured in order to disable consule logging in prod. I have in prod.properties file the following at the moment:

```
logging.file.name=/path/to/log/my-service.log
logging.level.org.springframework=WARN
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=90
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=10MB
```

Thanks.

Comment: Create a logback configuration locally which logs to the console instead of file. It is not more complicated then that.

Comment: interstingm but I dont have any lombok configuration apart from pom file. if you know, yo can answer?

Comment: What has this to do with lombok? It is logback configuration, which you have because you disabled the default which logs to console and file.

Comment: Ahh yes, I have logging.logback in the propery file! is there a property that take control on this behaviour

Comment: I have also logging.file.name=pathToFile but i don't want to remove this cause we need to test the log are saved there as well

Comment: Why would yu ned to remove it. Make a dedicated one for local development.

Comment: yeh I have different path for each env. anyway I updated the question base on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have logback.xml file in your class path(src/main/resources) like below and in your application.properties you need to mention this file for logging.

logbakc.xml

```
<configuration>

<!-- Console Appender -->
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- File Appender -->
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/application.log</file> <!-- Change the log file path as needed -->
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Logger Levels -->
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

application.properties

```
logging.config=logback.xml
```

and in production if you would like to disable console logs then just remove one line from logback.xml file like

```
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
```

and your application then should only write to file and not on console.

Comment: this  "logging.config=logback.xml" is not required as spring is able to load the file automatically. Instead of creating file for each environment, I'm using spring profile tags. But your answer helped with the main thing which is remove the CONSOLE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your logger configuration an option that in addition to the log file you want to print out your log into the concole. Keep the current config for prod and the changed one for dev. In case if you are using Log4J you will need to add an Appender. For other logging systems see the documentation how to do the same.

In addition, while this is not related to your question it might be interesting for you. There is a utility that can smartly filter your stacktrace making it much more concise filtering out irrelevant parts and leaving only the important parts. It also makes it much more readable when you need to analyze it. In your code, you may write something like this

```
log.error("Error occurred: {}", TextUtils.getStacktrace(e));
```

And you will get a filtered stacktrace. Here is a [Javadoc for getStracktrace()](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/TextUtils.html#getStacktrace-java.lang.Throwable-boolean-java.lang.String...-) method. The Utility comes with MgntUtils Open Source library written and maintained by me. The library may be obtained from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including Javadoc and source code). Also here is an [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) that describes the library including this feature. It is a bit outdated. The feature was improved in the currently latest version 1.7.0.0.

Comment: I have updaed the question can you review. I need to find the proerty that I need to include in prod as the current works fine for local and dev

Comment: I believe you need 2 different config files one for prod and one for dev. But in any case, I would advise not to print log in concole in any case, and your developers can open the logfile in an editor that can read updates on the fly

Comment: the productivuty is high when consule show everything. my question is for preparing for prod. I;m liiking for updating the properties file. as for your commentm I do have properties file for each env

Comment: If you have different configs for different envs it should give you all you need

Comment: I have the files but the config properties are the same, using lombok:  log.error("Error occurred: {}", e);  U can see it in both consule and file. need to change/.add soething to prod config to exlude the consule from showing

Comment: You will have to look for appropriate changes in config for your logger documentation.

Comment: I don't even have logback-spring.xml. becuase I'm happy with what we have now. logs show on both files and consule. I thought to get some sample config on how to di this

Comment: This is beyond the scope of this question, at least for me.